Expected hitting time of 2-d brownian motion with $B_0 = (x_0, y_0)$
I wonder if it is possible to calculate the expected time of hitting a ball of radius $R$ while the initial position of the 2-d Brownian motion is not at the origin but $(x_0,y_0)$ inside the ball.
I am inspired by the problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3877250/probability-brownian-motion-hitting-ball-in-dimension-2-and-3.\
Any advice is aprreciated.

$X_t := ||B_t||$ is a Bessel process (of dimension $2$) starting from $r_0 = \sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}$; the problem amounts to finding the distribution of the hitting time of $X$ at level $R$. This may be of help.

Let us consider a $\mathbb{R}^d,d\in \mathbb{N}$ Brownian motion $B=(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ started at $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$ in the interior of the $d$-ball of radius $R$. The process $Y_t:=\|B_t\|^2-dt$ is a martingale with respect to the natural  filtration of $B$. Indeed: if we write $B_t=(B_{1,t},...,B_{d,t})$ we get that $B_{t,k}^2-t$ are martingales - and a sum of martingales is a martingale. Define $\tau=\inf\{t:\|B_{t}\|=R\}$. By optional stopping theorem:
$$E[\|B_{\tau\wedge t}\|^2-d(\tau\wedge t)]=\|x\|^2\implies E[\tau\wedge t]=\frac{E[\|B_{\tau\wedge t}\|^2]-\|x\|^2}{d}$$
Furthermore, we know that $P(\tau<\infty)=1$ (so that $B_{\tau\wedge t}\to B_\tau$ a.s. as $t\to \infty$) and recall that $\|B_{\tau\wedge t}\|^2\leq R^2$. So MCT (on the lhs) and DCT (on the rhs) yield
$$E[\tau]=\frac{E[\|B_{\tau}\|^2]-\|x\|^2}{d}=\frac{R^2-\|x\|^2}{d}$$
because $P(\|B_{\tau}\|^2=R^2)=1$.
